# Need to show time difference in negative

Tags: sharepoint-online, date-time

I need to calculate a difference between two times and it should show negative value if the value is negative. Say Time 1 is 29/04/2019 11:30 PM and Time 2 is 29/04/2019 12:00 PM. I wat the difference shown as -11.50. Can someone help on this?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to show negative value when calculating two dates, you could configure the calculated column as below, select “Number” as the data type returned from this formula.

[image]

For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[SharePoint Calculate difference between two dates.](https://tracyvanderschyff.com/2016/12/02/calculate-difference-between-two-dates/)

Comment: is there someway to show negative values using text formatting, eg `TEXT(Finish-Start, “h:mm”)`.  more specifics are in my question here if anyone can help:  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/281535