# How to handle negative values when subtracting Start date/time from Finish date/time in a calculated column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list

**Desired Behaviour**

Calculate hours worked between two date/time columns, subtracting breaks (in minutes) and handling negative values (where a user has incorrectly entered a `Finish` time earlier than a `Start` time).

**What I've Tried**

I am using SharePoint Online modern list with a calculated column:

```
=TEXT((Finish-(1/24/60*Breaks))-Start,"h:mm")
```

The logic of the formula is essentially the same as `=TEXT(Finish-Start,"h:mm")` ([demonstrated in this Microsoft article](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/examples-of-common-formulas-in-sharepoint-lists-d81f5f21-2b4e-45ce-b170-bf7ebf6988b3)), but I am subtracting a dynamic amount of minutes from the `Finish` time to account for a user's `Breaks` throughout the day, per the logic in [this article](https://www.premierpointsolutions.com/training/help-and-how-to-articles/how-to-add-and-subtract-hours-and-minutes-from-date-and-time-fields-in-sharepoint-lists/).

This formulate is working as desired (it is outputting values like `9:00`, `7:00` and `8:30`) *except* it does not handle negative values (it outputs a positive value).

**Tests**

*Good:*

```
// Example A:  Finish is later than Start
// breaks are subtracted, and daily total is displayed, correctly

Start:        28/05/2020  8:45:00 AM
Finish:       28/05/2020  4:45:00 PM    
Breaks:       10
Daily Total:  7:50
```

*Bad:*

```
// Example B:  Finish is earlier than Start
// Daily Total shows positive value, instead of negative value

Start:        28/05/2020  9:00:00 AM    
Finish:       28/05/2020  12:00:00 AM   
Breaks:       30
Daily Total:  9:30
```

I tried changing the returned type from `Single line of text` to `Number` (per [this answer](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/262534/89805)) but it still displays a positive value.

When I test the formula in Excel, when `Finish` is earlier than `Start`, it outputs `#VALUE!`which is desirable as it shows that something is wrong with the `Finish` time entered.

**Question**

What formula can be used in a Calculated Column that:

- Displays output in `h:mm` format
- Returns some sort of `error` value if `Finish` time is earlier than `Start` time (and when `Finish` time is not defined)
- Returns accurate data if the employee enters shifts that span days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following seems to produce desired results, but I am hoping it could be made more succinct.

**Entries**

```
// representing Start, Finish and Breaks  

14/06/2020 9:00 AM , 14/06/2020 12:00 AM , 30
14/06/2020 9:00 AM , 14/06/2020 5:00 PM , 30 
14/06/2020 9:00 AM , [ blank ] , [ blank ]
```

**Formula**

```
IF(((Finish-(1/24/60*Breaks))-Start)>0, TEXT((Finish-(1/24/60*Breaks))-Start,"h:mm"), "valid Finish time required")
```

**Output**

```
valid Finish time required
7:30  
valid Finish time required
```

The logic uses the `IF()` statement:

```
IF(logical_test, [value_if_true], [value_if_false])
```

Sources:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-69aed7c9-4e8a-4755-a9bc-aa8bbff73be2
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/if-function-7025be14-5665-43d0-af20-8293d1fe9d3a

and essentially says:

> if `(Finish-Start)` is greater than 0,
>   return the `TEXT()` formatted result,
>   otherwise, return an error message

It is performing the evaluation twice though (for the `[logical_test]` and `[value_if_true]` values).

Can the `[logical_test]` value be saved as a variable so that it can be used again as the `[value_if_true]` parameter?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I wanted to calculate days to an Audit with indication if past. I was using this for an automation report:

```
=IF(ISERROR(DATEDIF(TODAY(),[Audit Date],"d")), -DATEDIF([Audit Date],TODAY(),"d"),DATEDIF(TODAY(),[Audit Date],"d"))
```